# Django app doesn't recognize static files

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, django-settings, static-files

I have a `Django` application which I'm not able to load static files in. My templates are perfectly loaded, but CSS and JS files can't be loaded. Here's my files:

```
zeinab@ZiZi:~/Desktop/MyProject$ tree
.
├── __init__.py
├── manage.py
├── myapp
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── lib
│   │   ├── decorators.py
│   │   ├── dorsa_forms.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── utils.py
│   ├── log
│   ├── media
│   │   └── admin
│   │       └── background_login
│   │           └── bg1.jpg
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── calendar.js
│   │   └── inbox.css
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── 404.html
│   │   ├── base.html
│   │   └── index.html
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── views.py
│   └── wsgi.py
└── requirements.txt

8 directories, 18 files
```

When I `runserver`, I get `"GET /static/file/url HTTP/1.1" 404 1265` for each CSS and JS file. Here's **MyProject/manage.py**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myapp.settings")
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

This is **MyProject/myapp/settings.py**:

```
import os
from django.contrib.messages import constants as messages

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'sorl.thumbnail',
    'myapp.lib',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

SITE_ID = 1

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myapp.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
        ],
    },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myapp.wsgi.application'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)
STATIC_ROOT = '/myapp/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

LOG_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'log')

DEBUG = True
```

This is **MyProject/myapp/urls.py**:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from .views import default
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', default, name='default'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

This is **MyProject/myapp/wsgi.py**:

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myapp.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**EDIT 1:**

I have changed **MyProject/myapp/urls.py** to the following:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.views import static
from django.contrib import admin
from .views import default

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', default, name='default'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^public/(?P<path>.*)$', static.serve, {
    'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT
}, name='url_public'),
]
```

I ended up to the same results.

**EDIT 2:**

I also tried using `urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)` instead of `urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()` and then trying to `collectstatic`; `collectstatic` completed successfully, but still opening URLs returns `"GET /static/file/url HTTP/1.1" 404 1265`.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

by

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

`staticfiles_urlpatterns()` is used only for debug to have a display view for your static file. As mentioned on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/staticfiles/ it **should never be used in production**.

Note: `STATIC_ROOT` & `MEDIA_ROOT` are used only when you're collecting the static (`collectstatic` with `manage.py`). It specifies the absolute path where to store the static and media files (usually `/var/www/myapp/static` and `/var/www/myapp/media`)

Answer (score 1):

In your `urls.py` you forgot to say how to "compute" the static route files.

Instead of this:

```
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Try this:

```
from django.views import static

urlpatterns = [
    # [...]
    url(r'^public/(?P<path>.*)$', static.serve, {
        'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT
    }, name='url_public'),
]
```

and in your template files (you didn't give a sample), try:

```
{% load static %}
<h1>{% static 'calendar.js' %}</h1>
```

Dont forget to use PyCharm because it helps so much for such things (it recognizes the path and you'll get the autocompletion in the template files (Ctrl+Space)).

Comment: When I `runserver`, I get `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'serve'`. Do you use a specific version of `Django`? I'm in the latest which is `1.11.5`.

Comment: Use PyCharm, go to the word "static", and pres "Alt-enter" "enter" so PyCharm will add the correct "import" on the top of your urls file, or manually add it: `from django.views import static`

Comment: That's the point: I use `static` from `django.conf.urls.static` as you can see in the question, but you're referring to `static` from `django.views`. Please mention that in your answer.

Comment: @ZeinabAbbasi Ok I've edited my answer, thanks for your suggestion. Is it working and did I answer /  put you on the right track?

Comment: I still get that `404` which I have provided in the question.